# CouchDB - Clean memory to avoid large binaries leaks

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, garbage-collection, erlang, couchdb

I have a Kubernets pod with a statefulset containing a CouchDB 3.2.1 instance using the official Helm chart (`bitnami/rabbitmq` from https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami), with a single node, no cluster mode (`clusterSize: 1`, `couchdbConfig.cluster.n: 1`, `couchdbConfig.couchdb.single_node: true`).

When I create a view, it requires a large amount of memory to build the index, but after finishing the process the memory usage remains high without automatic cleanup by gargabe collector.

I logged into the pod and called erl commands after finding the path to erl file:

```
> kubectl exec -it <pod_id> bash
> find . -name erl

./opt/couchdb/erts-11.2.2.9/bin/erl
> ./opt/couchdb/erts-11.2.2.9/bin/erl -setcookie monster
```

I got the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot get bootfile','/opt/couchdb/bin/start.boot'}}
init terminating in do_boot ({cannot get bootfile,/opt/couchdb/bin/start.boot})
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...
```

I found the path to a boot file (they are 2 boot files):

```
> find . -name *.boot

./opt/couchdb/releases/3.2.1/start_clean.boot
./opt/couchdb/releases/3.2.1/couchdb.boot
```

Then I launched the command again with `start_clean` boot (if I try with `couchdb` boot, it doesn't work), but it says I can't connect to running node process:

```
> ./opt/couchdb/erts-11.2.2.9/bin/erl -setcookie monster -boot ./opt/couchdb/releases/3.2.1/start_clean

Protocol 'inet_tcp': the name couchdb@mono-couchdb-0.mono-couchdb.miscellaneous.svc.cluster.local seems to be in use by another Erlang node
```

I tried with an another attempt connecting using a different name, now I can see Erlang shell:

```
> ./opt/couchdb/erts-11.2.2.9/bin/erl -setcookie monster -boot ./opt/couchdb/releases/3.2.1/start_clean -name clean@127.0.0.1

2023-05-29 09:36:28.958689 Multiple -~p given to erl, using the first, ~p
    name
    "clean@127.0.0.1"
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.2.2.9] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:1] [ds:4:1:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

=WARNING REPORT==== 29-May-2023::09:36:28.958689 ===
Multiple -name given to erl, using the first, "clean@127.0.0.1" 
Eshell V11.2.2.9  (abort with ^G)
```

Now I need to clean memory using garbage collector by Erlang shell:

```
(clean@127.0.0.1)1> lists:map(fun erlang:garbage_collect/1, processes()).

[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,
 true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,
 true,true,true,true,true,true|...]
```

But it seems not working, the memory usage remains high.

I have already tried to connect to the CouchDB erl process by remsh and connect to the specified job using jobs control mode, I can see CouchDB job but I don't know how I connect to it:

```
> find . -name remsh

./opt/couchdb/bin/remsh
> ./opt/couchdb/bin/remsh -c monster

2023-05-29 09:46:13.367824 Multiple -~p given to erl, using the first, ~p
    name
    "remsh279@127.0.0.1"
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.2.2.9] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:1] [ds:4:1:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

=WARNING REPORT==== 29-May-2023::09:46:13.367824 ===
Multiple -name given to erl, using the first, "remsh279@127.0.0.1"
*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***

User switch command
 --> r 'couchdb@127.0.0.1'
 --> j
   2* {'couchdb@127.0.0.1',shell,start,[]}
 --> c 2
*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***
```

Lastly I tried the suggestions given in this post: [Solving large binaries leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613027/solving-large-binaries-leak)

I manually set the environment variable `ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER=0`, but it seems to have no effect. I already checked if the environment variabile has been taken launching the following erl command (the result output shows the previous value):

```
> ./opt/couchdb/erts-11.2.2.9/bin/erl -setcookie monster -boot ./opt/couchdb/releases/3.2.1/start_clean -name clean@127.0.0.1
(clean@127.0.0.1)1> erlang:system_flag(fullsweep_after, 0).
0
```

Any suggestions? Thanks